# Android emulator > Extended Controls > Location

Tags: android, android-studio, geolocation, android-emulator

I have installed the current latest version of Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1
and created an emulator. When I run the emulator and go to the extended controls to set a location of my choice, I got the below UI.

I cannot find a place to define single locations (I do not want to simulate moving device)

**Where can I define the single location points in this tool?**

Send button doesn't work either.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two tabs: "Single points" and "Routes" in Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I already familiar with this screen and my issue was having this screen replaced by the screen I have shown in question.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. The screenshot from the first post ist shown, when the map can't load. In this case, the ui switches. My guess is that the text-only ui is shown when the map fails to load.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Machine restarted and all are normal as [Eugene P.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76836246/1920590) has shown.

Explanation:

First screenshot I have mention in my question is worked as a realtime location setter where I need to give exact latitude and longitude, when hit Send button the device will set to that location. But location is not saving as a pre defined place.